# ¿Cómo regular la velocidad de un motor con lógica difusa en arduino?

Tags: arduino

Tengo 1 entrada(sensor de humo) y 1 salida(motor). Hasta el momento en el circuito el sensor de humo funciona bien ya que dependiendo de la cantidad de humo imprime un mensaje en el monitor serial, pero la idea es que dependiendo de la cantidad de humo incremente o decremente la velocidad del motor y eso es lo que no sé cómo hacer. 
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
int s_humo = 0;
float t = 0;
float y;

int pin2=7;   //Entrada 2 del L293D
int pin7=8;  //Entrada 7 del L293D

  void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(pin2,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pin7, OUTPUT);
  }

  void loop(){
    t = analogRead(s_humo)
    +

      Serial.println("Cantidad de Humo:");
      Serial.println(t);
      float poco_humo = trapmf(t,-1000,25,288,350);
      float medio_humo = trapmf(t,300,350,680,700);
      float mucho_humo = trapmf(t,680,710,1000,1000);
      float c1=20;
      float c2=120;
      float c3=220;
      float w1 = poco_humo;
      float w2 = medio_humo;
      float w3 = mucho_humo;
      float c = (w1*c1+w2*c2+w3*c3)/(w1+w2+w3);
      Serial.print("La corriente del motor es:");
      Serial.println(c);
      analogWrite(pin2,c);
      delay(3000);
      }
    float trapmf(float x, float a, float b, float c, float d){
      if((x<=a) || (x>d))
        y=0.0;
        else if ((x>a) && (x<=b))
          y = (x-a)/(b-a);
        else if ((x>b) && (x<=c))
          y = 1;
        else if ((x>c) && (x<=d))
          y = (x-d)/(c-d);
        return y;    
  }
```

El sensor de humo está en el puerto Analogo 0

Comment: Podrias especificar un poco más? Que es lo que te falla? No sabes que algoritmo usar? No sabes como implementar cierto algoritmo? Lo tienes implementado pero no funciona? Gracias

Comment: Y en este momento que comportamiento tienes con tu codigo?

Comment: @Paco LordPakus El problema es que no se que algoritmo usar para que el motor gire y la velocidad del giro sea en proporcion a la cantidad de humo persibida por el sensor de humo, sin embargo si lo ejecuto asi como en el codigo de arriba, el resultado unicamente lo puedo ver a traves del monitor serial por ejemplo si la cantidad de humo es 400 me imprime "La corriente del motor es:" 120, la idea es que aparte de imprimir eso el motor gire a esa velocidad estableciendo que el rango de velocidad de giro es:[0 255]

Comment: Si no entiendo mal quieres regular la velocidad del motor en base a la cantidad de humo... Depende del motor, pero generalmente cuanto más voltaje más velocidad, el problema es que la relación no es lineal y que la curva que relaciona Voltaje con Velocidad depende de cada modelo de motor. Además tienes otro handicap y es que realmente los fabricantes no se hacen muy responsables de a que velocidad van los motores dado que desconocen que carga tienen que mover ( y tu también lo desconoces ;) ), factor importante en el cálculo de la velocidad final. **Solución profesional:**
Tendrías que pillar

Answer (score 2):

Probaría si el humo está aumentando o disminuyendo. Si aumenta aceleraría el motor y al revés:

```
float humo = 0;
float old_humo = 0;
void loop() {
     humo = analogRead(s_humo);
     if (humo > old_humo) {
         inc_ventilador();
     }
     if (humo < old_humo) {
         dec_ventilador();
     }        

     old_humo=humo;
}
```

También pondría algún limite inferior:

```
if (humo < NIVEL_TOLERANCIA) {
     parar_ventilidor();
}
```

Y recordemos que el **delay()** tiene sus peligros:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvoidDelay

Answer (score 1):

Si no te quieres complicar y el motor es dc ,lo mas facil es mapear la lectura del sensor a valores pwm y la salida pwm llevarla al l293:

```
 void loop() {
   int humo = analogRead(A0);
   int velocidad = map(humo,0,1023,0,255);
   analogWrite(pin2,velocidad);
 }
```

Asegurate que usas pines pwm,en tu sketch usas el 7 y 8 ,que por ejemplo en el UNO no son pwm (no has comentado que placa usas...)

Answer (score 0):

Yo te propongo que utilices la librería PID de arduino, busca y la encuentras seguro.

Según la variable de entrada (humo) obtendrás una respuesta a la salida (Motor)